# Asynchronous calls with await

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I have one question about `await` keyword. Here is some test code:

```
string username = await GetUsernameAsync();
// Some other code
var some_variable = username;
```

My question is: Does waiting starts at first line where we called async method or at the third line where we need the result of async method? Does some other code executes after `GetUsernameAsync` finishes its execution, or they are executing in parallel?

Comment: the waiting will be at the first line

Comment: This could easily be tested.  But basically the execution of these statements halts (waits) at the `await` keyword, as implied by the keyword itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens at the line where the `await` is.

If you want to delay the waiting, move the `await` to the moment you need the result. Remember the task, and move on. Then if you need the result, await the task:

```
Task<string> usernameTask = GetUsernameAsync();
// Some other code
var some_variable = await usernameTask;
```

Answer (score 1):

The first one. Take into account the await is just sugar syntax. It will be, more or less, replaced by a Task.Wait() to obtain the result. In fact, GetUsernameAsync() will return a Task, not a string.

Take a look to this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) to deep more how threads work with the asyn/await pattern